# Does the quantum state fidelity satisfy $F(\rho ,\sigma) \le F(\mathcal{A}(\rho), \mathcal{A}(\sigma))$ if ${\cal A}$ is a process involving ancillae?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, measurement, fidelity

It is a well known fact that the fidelity is preserved by unitary evolution, i.e.
$$
F(\rho ,\sigma) = F(U\rho U^\dagger, U\sigma U^\dagger),
$$
for any unitary operator $U$.

However in most quantum algorithms, we also use measurements to for instance uncompute an ancillary register. Imagine for instance that we want to implement a given unitary process $U$, however an ancillary qubit is necessary to perform that operation:
$$
V \left(|x\rangle |0\rangle\right) = \left(U |x\rangle\right) |+\rangle,
$$
therefore we can measure the last register and discard its value. If we write $\mathcal{A}$ the described process, it is true that:
$$
F(\rho ,\sigma) \le F(\mathcal{A}(\rho), \mathcal{A}(\sigma))?
$$

Comment: yes, the fidelity is monotone under arbitrary quantum channels. This is also mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your last statement is true. Fidelity is monotonic under the action of CPTP maps.

However, you can also use multiplicativity of fidelity, which is -
$$
F\bigg(\big( \rho_A \otimes \rho_B  \big) , \big( \sigma_A \otimes\sigma_B \big) \bigg) = F\big(\rho_A,\sigma_A\big) \cdot F\big(\rho_B,\sigma_B\big)\,.
$$
In your case, it becomes -

$$\begin{align}
F\bigg(\big( |x\rangle \otimes |0\rangle  \big) , \big( U|x\rangle \otimes |+\rangle \big) \bigg) &= F\big(|x\rangle,U|x\rangle\big) \cdot F\big(|0\rangle,|+\rangle\big)\,,\\
&= \big|\langle x|U |x\rangle\big|^2 \cdot \big|\langle 0|+\rangle\big|^2\,,\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot \big|\langle x|U |x\rangle\big|^2\,.
\end{align}
$$